# Regex: find occurrences and replace in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to find all occurrences of:

> src="cid:anyFileNameHere" alt="watch for the other quotes"

and replace with:

> src="http://myServerURl/anyFileNameHere.gif" alt="watch for the other quotes"

It's the `.gif` part that I find difficult as it must be before the next `"`

Comment: if it's an html you are better off with html parser..there are n number of cases wer a `regex` would fail...

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ, this is a question about search-and-replace in a text editor. Not sure that the "use an HTML parser" response is so applicable in this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple find and replace you could use:

```
Find: src="cid:([^"]+)"

Replace: src="http://myServerURl/$1.gif"
```

This is matching `src="cid:` then capturing anything that is not a `"` up to the next `"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

Find

```
(src=")cid:(\w+)(" alt="[\w\s]+")
```

Replace

```
$1http://myServerURI/$2.gif$3
```

You may have to tweak it based on your exact requirements.  This matches alphanumeric characters, underscores, and spaces in the alt section.  It matches alphanumeric characters and underscores for the filename.

*Note:* this solution is tested in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Search for:

```
src="cid:(.*?)" alt="(.*?)"
```

Replace by:

```
src="http://myServerURl/$1.gif" alt="$2"
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?333ee)